# Get database result using Where and Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

I started creating a new application using **Laravel** Framework and i have two models **user** and **preference**

user model contain :

```
public function preference()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Preference::class);
}
```

preference Model contain :

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

How can i use where statement in my controller for ie : where preferencesTable.cityField = 'NY'

this is my controller code :

```
$users = User::where(['field in preference table' => 'NY'])->preference;
```

I would like to get users data and preferences data using where clause

NB : * I have a field called city in my preferences Table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should return you only users which have city = NY in their preference:

```
User::whereHas('preference', function($query) {
    $query->where('city', 'NY');
})->get()
```

Comment: Thank you, why i get Null $user = Auth::user();
        dd($user->gender);

Comment: Auth::user() works only if there is logged in user. You should login first